# 'int' object has no attribute __get__item error when training model with tflearn?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm getting this error when I tried to train a custom grayscale image dataset (using 2 images only) with the example mnist code from tflearn. The images are all of different sizes, around the range of (3000,3000) height and width. This is my error:

```
Run id: convnet_images
Log directory: /tmp/tflearn_logs/
Exception in thread Thread-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 186, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 221, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 187, in slice_array
    return X[start]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

and this is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

image = imread('image.jpg')
image2 = imread('image2.jpg')

image3 = imread('image3.jpg')
image4 = imread('image4.jpg')

image = np.resize(image, (256, 256, 1))
image2 = np.resize(image2, (256, 256, 1))
image3 = np.resize(image3, (256, 256, 1))
image4 = np.resize(image4, (256, 256,1 ))

image_train = np.stack((image, image2), axis = 0)
image_test = np.stack((image3, image4), axis = 0)
# # build the neural net
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

network = input_data(shape = [None, 256, 256, 1], name = 'input')
network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation = 'relu', regularizer = 'L2')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = local_response_normalization(network)
# network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation = 'relu', regularizer = 'L2')
# network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
# network = local_response_normalization(network)
network = fully_connected(network, 128, activation = 'tanh')
network = dropout(network, 0.8)
network = fully_connected(network, 1, activation = 'softmax')
network = regression(network, optimizer = 'adam', learning_rate = '0.001', name = 'target')

#Training
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose = 3)
model.fit({'input': image_train}, {'target': 0}, n_epoch = 20, batch_size = 1,
          validation_set = ({'input': image_test}, {'target': 0}),
          snapshot_step = 100, show_metric = True, run_id = 'convnet_images')
```

I highly suspect the error comes from the fact that my grayscale pixel intensity value is a np.uint8 and not an np array. Meaning to say, when I `print type(image_train[0, 0, 0, 0])` which gives the pixel value, it is a np.uint8, which probably means the code in tflearn cannot access value using an index selector `__getitem__` (from what I've read so far). But how can I get the pixel value to become an np array? Is np.resize the correct way to handle grayscale images? Because ideally speaking, this should work for colored images which means the 4th dimension - the channel pixel values of RGB - have to be an np array that houses the 3 pixel values (and so understandably the tflearn code probably requested to access the pixel values using `__getitem__`. But this is my guess only; I'm still unsure of how to go about this.

Comment: Can you treat your grayscale image as a RGB image with each channel having an equal value?

Comment: Hmm I wanted to but wouldn't that cause a 2x increase in the data size to handle? I think it'll be hard to scale up if I have many images to handle. Is there a permanent solution to resizing the image size properly?

Comment: I have discovered an error in my code, that is my Y value isn't formatted as a 2 by 1 np array and is instead just a float. Upon fixing this error, the index error is now gone, but I have now gotten to another problem which is found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955168/tensorflow-cast-string-to-float-is-not-supported-error-when-using-tflearn-despi
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OP self-answered in a comment:

> I have discovered an error in my code, that is my Y value isn't formatted as a 2 by 1 np array and is instead just a float. Upon fixing this error, the index error is now gone.